# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Day'

Tags: python, lifetimes-python

I've been getting the error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Day'.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html

```
from lifetimes.datasets import load_transaction_data
from lifetimes.utils import summary_data_from_transaction_data

transaction_data = load_transaction_data()
print(transaction_data.head())
"""
                  date  id
0  2014-03-08 00:00:00   0
1  2014-05-21 00:00:00   1
2  2014-03-14 00:00:00   2
3  2014-04-09 00:00:00   2
4  2014-05-21 00:00:00   2
"""


summary = summary_data_from_transaction_data(transaction_data, 'id', 'date', observation_period_end='2014-12-31')

print(summary.head())
```

Comment: Show the *complete* stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

You might have resolved this on your own - but thought to post it for anyone facing this issue.

I faced the exact same issue but the reason was that I was using an older version of the Lifetimes package. I was able to resolve it after updating Lifetimes to **version 0.11.1**.